# Force AUCTeX to parse the whole document

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

I'm using `AUCTeX 11.87` along with `emacs 24.3` for writing my `LaTeX` documents. This is working nicely with one exception: The parsing.

My document structure is as follows:

```
./
Master.tex
Chapter_1.tex
Chapter_2.tex
...
header/
header/header.tex
header/packages.tex
header/options.tex
...
```

Where `Master.tex` `\input`s `header.tex` which in turn inputs all files in `header/`. Furthermore `Master.tex` includes the `Chapter_N.tex` files within the `document` environment.

Here comes the problem: AUCTeX does not generate the parse files (the ones in the `auto` folder) until I have actually opened the file. Meaning that until I have not opened and saved the `header/packages.tex` and `header/header.tex` files AUCTeX does not know about the loaded packages and thus their commands/environments.

An now the question: Can I force AUCTeX to (re)parse the whole source-tree (and then reload the style hooks for all open documents)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all files are in the same directory, or in subdirectories under it, open the master file and issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-auto-generate` <kbd>RET</kbd> and as `TeX file or directory` insert the directory of the master file and as `AUTO lisp directory` the `auto/` subdirectory of the previous directory.

For instance, if your master file is placed in `~/my-document/`, insert `~/my-document/` at the first prompt and `~/my-document/auto` at the second one (you can also use relative paths if you prefer them).

Comment: You need to force reparsing in a sub-document (`C-c C-n`), but it works! Thanks.